# Change boolean after using value in RHS of equation?

Tags: java, c#, c++, boolean

I'm not sure if there's even a way to do it, but I figure this is the best place to ask.

I want to change a boolean's value immediately after using it (or before, would only require a semantic change), but in the same line.
The intended effect would be the same as this code:

```
bool flag, tempFlag; //whatever names
...

tempFlag = flag;
flag = !flag;
```

But I was wondering if there's a shorthand way of doing that, in a single line. Something like `tempFlag = flag!;` :P

For example, you can change the value of an int immediately after using its value in a single line, as in:

```
int x = y++;
```

**Is there a short way of writing such an action?**

My specific problem is in C#, but I am curious if any other popular language has such a way.

Comment: Why write one line of syntax other people may not understand when you can write two where everyone knows what you are doing?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for your opinion. Yes, I agree with you in most cases. However, this is just a personal experiment project that I'm working on and trying to keep no. of lines to a minimum, so I don't feel the need to make the code incredibly readable (as long as I get the context, I know I'll understand it).

Comment: You say that now but what about in three years when you come back to it and you forgot about it. Then you will wondering what the heck you where doing.  I can appreciate trying to keeps the number of lines down but you should not sacrifice readability for it IMHO.

Comment: you could also write your own type implicitly convertible to/from bool and overload ++ I suppose..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tempFlag = !(flag = !flag);
```

should work in all mentioned languages. `flag = !flag` returns the new value, which is then inverted again and put into `tempflag`. But as NathanOliver mentioned, I see no need to do something like this. If you want it to be threadsafe (which is the only application I can imagine for something like this, and I'm not even sure if it would work) use a thread lock to make it so.

Comment: Very creative (and obscure).